# How to copy executables in dockerfile multi-stage

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have an django image with multi-stage build. I install dependencies required by the the app, e.g heroku, psql, etc in the first stage. But when when I copy the bin path to the 2nd stage, they don't work in the app.
`dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-slim as base

WORKDIR /test


# libpq-dev and gcc help with psycopg2
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y curl unzip git libgtk-3-0 locales postgresql-client libpq-dev gcc gnupg \
  && apt-get clean all \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq \
    && apt-get clean all

  # Install yarn
RUN npm install -g yarn

RUN curl https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.13.6/terraform_0.13.6_linux_amd64.zip -o /tmp/terraform.zip && cd /tmp && unzip /tmp/terraform.zip -d /usr/local/bin
RUN curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh 

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir pipenv \
  && pipenv install --deploy --system \
  && mv src/* /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /test

COPY post-install.sh /test
COPY media.tar.gz /test

COPY --from=base /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
COPY --from=base /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=base /test/static/ /test/static/


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# Run the image as a non-root user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" django
USER django

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/post-install.sh"]
```

When I run the app, and exec, if I run `npm` or `psql`, `heroku` I get command not found. How can I solve this

Comment: Please, post your build log.

Comment: Don't think it will help that much, the new version of docker conceals the logs under once command

Comment: Does your _application_ need to run `npm`, or does it just serve the front-end as static files?  `psql`, or does it use a Python-native SQL client?

Comment: the post install script runs those commands, psql, npm, heroku, tar, git.. But they are not available in the 2nd stage